# Delaunay triangulation makes me lose symmetry

Tags: matlab, triangulation, delaunay

I am using Delaunay triangulation to split polygons into triangles. I work on FEM with a large code, and one of my "checkpoints" is symmetry (if the data is symmetric, the output has to be symmetric too). However, since I have no control over the Delaunay triangulation, it makes me lose the symmetry.

I have written a small code that illustrates my problem: we consider two disjoint triangles and a big rectangle that intersects them. We want to triangulate the subtractions of those triangles with the rectangle:

```
clear all
close all
warning off % the warning is about duplicate points, not important here

figure
hold on

p =[.3 .3
.4 .3
.3 .4
.7 .6
.6 .7
.7 .7]; % coordinates of the points for the triangles

px = 1/3;
py = 1/3;
lx = 1/3;
ly = 1/3; % size and position of the rectangle

% rearrange the polygon with clockwise-ordered vertices
[x1,y1]=poly2cw([px; px+lx; px+lx; px],[py; py; py+ly; py+ly]); % rectangle

patch(x1,y1, 1, 'EdgeColor', 'k');

for i=1:2

    pc = p(3*i-2:3*i,:); % current triangle
    % rearrange the polygon with clockwise-ordered vertices
    [x0,y0]=poly2cw(pc(:,1),pc(:,2)); % triangle

    [x2,y2] = polybool('intersection',x1,y1,x0,y0); % intersection
    [x3,y3] = polybool('subtraction',x0,y0,x2,y2); % subtraction

    DT = delaunayTriangulation(x3,y3);

    triplot(DT,'Marker','o')

end
XL = xlim; xlim(XL+[-1 +1]*diff(XL)/10);
YL = ylim; ylim(YL+[-1 +1]*diff(YL)/10);
axis equal;
box on;
```

[image: delaunay triangulation]

As you can see, the Delaunay triangulation does not have the same behaviour in both triangles, hence the loss of symmetry.

Is there a simple way to recover symmetry?

I use Matlab R2013a.

Comment: I decided to add another answer for others to see both results as a reference.

Answer (score 0):

Seem like you are using MatLab R2013 because in my R2011b there is no `delaunayTriangulation` function. To be able to run your code I changed it slightly:

```
clear all
close all
warning off % the warning is about duplicate points, not important here

figure
hold on

p =[.3 .3
    .4 .3
    .3 .4
    .7 .6
    .6 .7
    .7 .7]; % coordinates of the points for the triangles

px = 1/3;
py = 1/3;
lx = 1/3;
ly = 1/3; % size and position of the rectangle

% rearrange the polygon with clockwise-ordered vertices
[x1,y1]=poly2cw([px; px+lx; px+lx; px],[py; py; py+ly; py+ly]); % rectangle

patch(x1,y1, 1, 'EdgeColor', 'k');

for i=1:2

    pc = p(3*i-2:3*i,:); % current triangle
    % rearrange the polygon with clockwise-ordered vertices
    [x0,y0]=poly2cw(pc(:,1),pc(:,2)); % triangle

    [x2,y2] = polybool('intersection',x1,y1,x0,y0); % intersection
    [x3,y3] = polybool('subtraction',x0,y0,x2,y2); % subtraction

    %DT = delaunayTriangulation(x3,y3);
    %triplot(DT)

    % This is triangulation of subtraction
    DT = delaunay(x3,y3);
    triplot(DT,x3,y3, 'Marker','.', 'Color','r')

    % This is triangulation of intersection
    DT = delaunay(x2,y2);
    triplot(DT,x2,y2, 'Marker','o', 'Color','b', 'LineWidth',1)

end
axis equal;
axis tight;
box on;

XL = xlim; xlim(XL+[-1 +1]*diff(XL)/10);
YL = ylim; ylim(YL+[-1 +1]*diff(YL)/10);

text(0.5,0.55,'triangulation of subtraction',  'HorizontalAlignment','center', 'VerticalAlignment','bottom', 'Color','r');
text(0.5,0.45,'triangulation of intersection', 'HorizontalAlignment','center', 'VerticalAlignment','top',    'Color','b');
```

Here is the result I see

[image]

Is it similar to yours?
Could you add an image to your question describing what is wrong with the result you get?

Comment: Thank you for your help.
See first message for edits.
I use the `delaunayTriangulation` function because when performing the triangulation (with `delaunayTriangulation` or simply `delaunay`), it can result in triangles outside of the geometry (we cannot see it on your figure right now because the plot of the intersection comes after the plot of the subtraction; try to plot only the first `DT` in your code and you'll see it). For this reason, I use the `delaunayTriangulation` function with edge constraints then the `isInterior` function to keep only triangles inside the geometry.

Comment: Secondly, weirdly your code gives me a different result, similar to the result of my own code (in message #1).

Comment: Yes, I've seen the red triangles exactly under the blue ones. I took yuor updated code and changed it to use `delaunayTri` (predescessor of `delaunayTriangulation` in R2011b). But I see the same result as before, not like yours. The `delaunayTriangulation` class appeared in R2013a according to http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/release-notes.html So may be they also changes simething behind it? Or this is a bug :/

Answer (score 0):

It seems this is not a bug.
Your result comes from your data, actually.

I played a little with your code

```
clear all
close all
warning off % the warning is about duplicate points, not important here

figure
hold on

p =[.3 .3
.4 .3
.3 .4
.7 .6
.6 .7
.7 .7]; % coordinates of the points for the triangles

px = 1/3;
py = 1/3;
lx = 1/3;
ly = 1/3; % size and position of the rectangle

% rearrange the polygon with clockwise-ordered vertices
[x1,y1]=poly2cw([px; px+lx; px+lx; px],[py; py; py+ly; py+ly]); % rectangle

patch(x1,y1, 1, 'EdgeColor', 'k');

for i=1:2

    pc = p(3*i-2:3*i,:); % current triangle
    % rearrange the polygon with clockwise-ordered vertices
    [x0,y0]=poly2cw(pc(:,1),pc(:,2)); % triangle

    [x2,y2] = polybool('intersection',x1,y1,x0,y0); % intersection
    [x3,y3] = polybool('subtraction',x0,y0,x2,y2); % subtraction

    % This is for R2013a
    %DT = delaunayTriangulation(x3,y3);
    %triplot(DT,'Marker','o');

    % This is for R2011b
    %DT = DelaunayTri(x3,y3);
    %triplot(DT,'Marker','o');

    % This is plain delaunay version
    DT = delaunay(x3,y3);
    triplot(DT,x3,y3,'Marker','o')
    
    % we break here to analyze the first triangulation
    break

end
XL = xlim; xlim(XL+[-1 +1]*diff(XL)/10);
YL = ylim; ylim(YL+[-1 +1]*diff(YL)/10);
axis equal;
box on;

% % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % %
% Checking the triangulation
% % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % %

% Wrong triangulation for i=2 is hard-coded
DT2     = [
    2 1 6
    6 5 2
    5 3 2
    5 4 3
    2 3 1 ];

figure;
hold all;
triplot(DT2,x3,y3,'Marker','o', 'Color','r', 'LineWidth',1)
axis equal;
axis tight;
box on;
XL = xlim; xlim(XL+[-1 +1]*diff(XL)*0.5);
YL = ylim; ylim(YL+[-1 +1]*diff(YL)*0.5);

% circumcircle: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/17300
ca = linspace(0,2*pi);
cx = cos(ca);
cy = sin(ca);

hl = [];
for k=1:size(DT2,1)
    tx  = x3(DT(k,:));
    ty  = y3(DT(k,:));
    [r,cn]=circumcircle([tx,ty]',0);
    if ~isempty(hl)
        %delete(hl);
    end
    fprintf('Circle %d: Center at (%.23f,%.23f); R=%.23f\n',k,cn,r);
    text( cn(1),cn(2), sprintf('c%d',k) );
    hl = plot( cx*r+cn(1), r*cy+cn(2), 'm-' );
    drawnow;
    %pause(3); %if you prefere to go slowly 
end
```

And this is the output I seee:

> Circle 1: Center at (0.28333333333333333000000,0.35000000000000003000000); R=0.05270462766947306400000
> Circle 2: Center at (0.34999999999999998000000,0.34999999999999998000000); R=0.02357022603955168100000
> Circle 3: Center at (0.28333333333333338000000,0.34999999999999992000000); R=0.05270462766947289800000
> Circle 4: Center at (0.35000000000000003000000,0.28333333333333355000000); R=0.05270462766947290500000
> Circle 5: Center at (0.35000000000000003000000,0.28333333333333333000000); R=0.05270462766947312000000

And the figure:

[image]

So circles 1 and 3 as well as circles 4 and 5 are almost the same.
So the difference between yours and mine results might come even from round-off errors, because the corresponding four points are on the same circle within the float math precision. You have to redesign your points in order to get reliable result which does not depend on such things.

Have fun ;o)

Comment: Ok, so I have tried the `DelaunayTri` function too. I gives me the same result as before (with `delaunay` and `delaunayTriangulation`).

I understand what you did with the circumcircle thing. But I am not sure it comes from round-off errors. Because the other triangle still has the good triangulation (by 'good' I mean a triangulation that has a x/y symmetry).

Do you think it is worth signalling this to Matlab?

Comment: I think that this situation is the result of round-off errors. Just comment the `break` in my code at the end of the `for i=1:2` loop and you'll see that among another 5 circles (for the case i=2) there are also two pairs of almost identical ones. Also it might be a good idea to check MathWorks documentation maybe they also changed something in the algorithms meanwhile.

Comment: I commented the `break` in your code, and also changed the hard-code for the circles accordingly `if i==1
    DT2     = [
        2 1 6;
        6 5 2;
        5 3 2;
        5 4 3;
        2 3 1 ];
else
    DT2 = [
        3 1 6;
        4 2 3;
        5 3 6;
        5 4 3;
        2 3 1 ];
    
end`
As you said there are two pairs of almost identical ones there too. So now I understand that it may be the round-off errors...

Comment: I had an 'official' anwser from the technical support:

"This is definitely due to sensitivity to small rounding differences.
To see the effect, run the attached, modified script several times and observe that
the results are different every time.
It adds very small random errors(magnitude ~1e-12) to the vertices of your polygon defined by x3,y3.

I can only agree with the stackoverflow answer: 
"You have to redesign your points in order to get reliable result which does not depend on such things."

Basically, you cannot depend on delaunay triangulation preserving this kind of symmetry."